# Generate screenshots from excel sheets without using win32com library

Tags: python, excel, excel-interop, win32com

I've written a python script which fills an excel file template with data (here i use openpyxl) and i create an image of every sheet with excel2img library to send it as an embedded content in an email.
My problem is that excel2img uses win32com library.

Now i search a library / option to create a image of my excel sheets without using win32com library.

This script should be executed on a Windows Server by Windows Task Scheduler with the option "Run whether user is logged on or not". This won't work with win32com.

Has anybody an idea how to realize this without win32com?

Thanks!

My previous question to this topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477697/how-to-parse-convert-a-excel-file-xlsx-to-html-without-using-win32-in-python

--

Does anyone know if Python is interop capable (like C++ / C#)?

Comment: What makes it not work with win32com? Does it run, but fail, or does it not run at all?

Comment: it fails... it is not possible to start a program which use the microsoft com interface via task scheduler and not logged on user... a known but not solved problem on windows

Answer (score 0):

You may try with Pillow's [ImageGrab](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/ImageGrab.html) if you have the bounding box dimensions.

[Here's](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/349e220b0a7e9396843e039c5f481d545d28fa91/src/_imaging.c) its signature, afaik it doesn't involve win32com:

```
extern PyObject* PyImaging_GrabScreenWin32(PyObject* self, PyObject* args);
```

Comment: I will try it out and then report back

Comment: I tried this idea, but this won't work, your code example also uses win32 and ImageGrab.grab / .grabClipboard, too. My Problem is that I can't open Excel if the useer is not logged on...